# После слова "самолет" запятая ставится?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

При отсутствии проездных документов, а также посадочного талона в самолет, оплата не производится.

Answer (score 3):

*При отсутствии проездных документов, а также посадочного талона в самолет оплата не производится.*

Нет условий постановки запятой.  Оплата не производится когда? при каких условиях? При отсутствии проездных документов, а также посадочного талона в самолёт. Это не придаточное предложение, не причастный оборот, не уточнение,никаких  причин для обособления нет.

Answer (score 0):

Да,запятая ставится. Вторая запятая закрывает условие, а первая разделяет однородные члены.